# Notification displays [object Object] instead of message

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to display my answers from google form but it instead notifies me with`[object Object]` instead
In my other forms it run just fine with the same code. It displays the responses properly but in this form it only displays object Object instead. I don't have much knowledge in coding so I'm kind of stuck.

```js
// Line Notify

function onFormSubmit() {

    var form = FormApp.openById('1AmVDW-0uUhE-6EiGBKRkSIYNk2CPaoCvAIjF3ZCPfOI');
    var fRes = form.getResponses();

    var formResponse = fRes[fRes.length - 1];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('E.SP Incentive');
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
    var responses = form.getResponses();
   
    var msg = 'Gas Forklift'
       + ' \n' + itemResponses[5].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[5].getResponse()
       + ' \n' + itemResponses[0].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[0].getResponse()
       + ' \n' + itemResponses[1].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[1].getResponse() 
       + ' \n' + itemResponses[2].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[2].getResponse() 
       + ' \n' + itemResponses[3].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[3].getResponse()
       + ' \n' + itemResponses[4].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[4].getResponse()
       
  
        sendLineNotify(msg);

}
function sendLineNotify(message) {

    var token = ["XoAJwSgiMgQRen6Lit5sLstJgp0GILbXKXsRrG19yZB"];
    var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "payload": "message=" + message,
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
        }
    };

    UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify", options);
}
```

Comment: Also you're declaring token as an array of 1 string. I believe you should be removing the square brackets around it so that it is a string instead.

Answer (score 0):

[image: I Think there the error]

check if + is necessary in the code;
and you have declared msg keyword twice

Comment: i seems that the second msg was not necessary but even though i deleted it. it still displays object object